# Akka BalancingDispatcher Config

Tags: java, scala, akka

I have created a file application.conf in src/main/resources that looks like this:

```
balancing-dispatcher {
  type = BalancingDispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
}
```

There is nothing else in the file.

Upon creating a new Actor (through my test suite using Akka TestKit) that tries to use the dispatcher, I receive this error message:

```
[WARN] [04/13/2013 21:55:28.007] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [Dispatchers] Dispatcher [balancing-dispatcher] not configured, using default-dispatcher
```

My program then runs correctly, albeit using only a single thread.

Furthermore, I intend to package my program into a library.  The akka docs state this:

```
If you are writing an Akka application, keep you configuration in application.conf at
the root of the class path. If you are writing an Akka-based library, keep its 
configuration in reference.conf at the root of the JAR file.
```

I have tried both of these methods so far, but neither has worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since your `application.conf` is not found I can only assume that `src/main/resources` is not part of your build path (cannot comment further without knowing which tool you use for building).

One small thing: why do you use `"thread-pool-executor"` in there? We found the default `"fork-join-executor"` to scale better.

Your comment about the one thread suggests that you are creating just one actor; using a `BalancingDispatcher` does not automagically create more actors, you will have to tell Akka to do that somehow (e.g. creating multiple instance of that same actor manually or via a `Router`).

The question of `reference.conf` vs. `application.conf` is more one of the nature of the settings. If your library wants to get its own settings from the config, then default values should go into `reference.conf`; that is the design concept and the reason why this file is always implicitly merged in. Defaults should only be in that file, never in the code.

Comment: It is part of my build path as I can access it through system resources. Eg println(getClass().getResource("/reference.conf")) correctly lists the file.

I added a duplicate file to src/test/resources, but the issue persists.

I also tried chaning the file to akka { actor { balancing-dispatcher... } }.  

I cannot find an example .conf file to with custom dispatchers in the akka-samples, is there somewhere I can download a sample project that does do this?

Note that I am also spawning a collection of Actors.

Comment: May I suggest you post all the details on the akka-user ML? You seem to have some special problem which awkward to debug on StackOverflow.